# Custom chart without range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

[EmbeddedChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder.html) allows to set range out of sheet:

```
builder.addRange(sheet.getRange('A1:A2'))
```

Is there way to set chart data without a range? Something like this seems should be reasonable:

```
builder.setData([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Why? `Charts` class might be able to do it

Comment: You can try with the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts), but I don't see why using ranges is a problem.

Comment: @TheMaster do you know exactly how to do it? I just can't find a way except using `Range`

Comment: @Jescanellas As I understand from documentation `Range` can't be created without actual range in sheet: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: I don't think there's a way. I'm suggesting using ``Chart`` class instead of ``EmbeddedChart`` class. You can get a image, which you can  insert into spreadsheet. Alternatively and preferably, You should use [tag:google-vizualization] in a html file, which can be shown live in a sidebar.

Comment: @TheMaster that's what I needed, thanks. If you leave answer I mark it as a solution. Tried chart and it works, will also check google visualisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to set values directly from a array to [`Embedded Chart builder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder.html).

#### Possible workarounds:

- **Charts service:**   *Static Server side charts*
  Use [`Charts`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table-builder) class to create a datatable and use it to create a server side chart. This could  then be inserted as a *static* image in the spreadsheet.
- **Html Charts:** *Live charts from Google viz*
  Use [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization)([Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)) to create a *live* html chart and show it in the sidebar/modal dialogs.
- **Google sheets range:**
  Set the array to a range in sheets and add that range to embedded chart builder.